# instance variable defined by concatenation of strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Needing to generate a partial with content dynamically-defined by input parameter `month_id`, I attempted te set an instance variable needed to the collection_select menu, based on a concatenation of strings.

```
<%= myevents = "@events_" + month_id.to_s %>

<% instance_variable_set("@events", myevents) %>
<%= f.collection_select(:event_id, @events, [...]
```

However, rails complains that is is handling a string `undefined method`map' for "@events_01":String`, rather than the desired collection. so how can this instance variable be dynamically called then?

Comment: Dynamically building variable names feels wrong to me. Why do you need to do that? Why can't you use a hash or a similar data structure with the month used as the key? What do you try to achieve?

Comment: well, it is to call a partial.  The partial has locals which whould allow to grab only the selected elements.  It seemed more natural and efficient to have the controller method generate the selected elements, rather than doing the filtering process at view-build time.

Comment: Try `instance_variable_set("@events", instance_variable_get("@events_" + month_id.to_s))`. Anyway, it looks weird and wrong.

Comment: Weird, but functional. Post suggestion as answer for upvote please. I guess performance in the end will be the measure of what is best...

Comment: The proper way to achieve this would be to use the array for `@events` and to get/set `@events[month_id]`.

Comment: I would argue that readability and maintainability are important too (and most of the time are more important than performance). Perhaps there is is a better solution. What is `month_id`? Where is it coming from? And how do you generate the various `@events_` instance variables?

Comment: FWIW, besides `instance_variable_get`, `myevents = eval("@events_#{month_id}")` would work.

Comment: useful points.  Admittedly, the question was vague on this point. month_id is actually not an object attribute, only a counter of months into the future.

Comment: Even if `month_id` is a random value from the interval `[0...Float::INFINITY)`, the way to go is an array with `month_id` being an index.